# attach content db = 404

Tags: configuration

On our test/dev environment, I had a web application which I deleted and re-created. Using the Central Admin I re-attached the content database to the re-created web application. Problem is, visiting the site brings up a 404 error. If I visit a site admin page for the site (e.g. /_layouts/settings.aspx), I get a rather plain "An unexpected error has occurred." page. I fired up ULS and the admin page visit turns up a string of "Unknown SPRequest error occured. More information: 0x80070002". I googled that up, and while there were hits, none of 'em made the pain stop. Fwiw, this is SP2010, Apr 2012 upd.

I'm open to suggestions on what to try next, I've bing'd and googled this a hundred times today and am tired already!

Comment: How did you migrate the content database to the SQL server. Incase you restored it incorrectly or tried to override with the same name of an existing content database, you will face this error.

Comment: The fact you can't even hit the system pages means theres something fairly wrong. I'd ensure that your default AAMs are the same as what they were to start with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up getting it working again, but I cannot say my solution was optimal. I deleted and recreated the web application associated with the content database. When I recreated the web app, I specified the original content database name instead of the new random-guid one you get when making a new web app. I did an IISRESET out of superstition, and therafter, the content was available again and order was restored to the universe.