# restore content DB issue-sp 2010

Tags: service-application

After restore the content db from xxx environment to yyy environment.

1. create web application
2. add content DB(we mapped to restored db).
3. sites not up. shows 404 error occurred
4. view site collection, found the toplevel site collectio ins missing(i mean "/")

Please any1 help me on this. where went wrong ?

Comment: maybe the World Wide Web Publishing Service is not activated?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if restoring content DB clears configuration cache as well for that specific Content DB,

You can follow this [blog](http://spandps.com/2011/10/28/sharepoint-web-front-end-http-404-response-but-no-errors-in-the-log-sp2010-ps2010-msproject-projectserver-in/) who had similar kind of problem and he solved it by clearing cache.

Similar kind of problem solved in this [question](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/39194/attach-content-db-404) by a different way.

Also can you go to following pages for your top site collection that you said you can view and check ULS Viewer to find any errors come up

- /_layouts/settings.aspx
- /_layouts/create.aspx

**EDIT**

Another Problem can be if any pages or content is corrupted e.g. "default.aspx" as explained in this [Blog](http://objectmix.com/sharepoint/295556-404-not-found-but-site-really-there.html)